# Regular expression for value incease

Tags: regex

Is there possible with `reg ex` to find a string, say `xxVAR1`, `xxVAR2`, `xxVAR3`, where `VARx` is a number and for each match increase `VARx` say by 20%?

Answer (score 3):

No, regex is pattern finding system. It cant calculate by its own. What you can do is find the first one by regex, then extract, calculate in your programming language and create a new regex. But there could be better ways around this task. Regex has no understanding of the math in numbers, for it every number is just a character that could be found.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot exactly achieve what you want using regex. You have to use regex in addition to some high level language.

You can use this regex as a base

```
/(..VAR[0-9]{1})/
```

You can use Python or language of your choice to achieve following

```py
regex = '/(..VAR[0-9]{%num%})/'

for i in range(1, 5): 
    new_regex = regex.replace('{%num%}', str(i))
    # Do whatever you want
```